# setuid(0) and system fails

Tags: c, linux, root, setuid

I have a program running in C. This needs to execute an "iptables" command using system.

I tried

```
setuid(0); 
system("iptables .... ");
```

setuid and system do not coexist. from the system man page

> Do not use system() from a program
>   with set-user-ID or set-group-ID
>   privileges, because strange values 
>   for  some
>          environment  variables  might  be used to subvert system integrity. 
>   Use the exec(3) family of functions
>   instead,
>          but not execlp(3) or execvp(3).  system() will not, in fact, work
>   properly from programs with
>   set-user-ID or set-
>          group-ID  privileges  on  systems  on  which /bin/sh is bash
>   version 2, since bash 2 drops
>   privileges on startup.
>          (Debian uses a modified bash which does not do this when invoked as
>   sh.)

how can I overcome my problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might help. It's untested but should work.

```
    char * const argv[] = {"/sbin/iptables", "-L", NULL};

    pid = fork();
    switch (pid) {
            case -1:
                    /* handle error */
            case 0:
                    execv("/sbin/iptables", argv);
                    /* handle error if you get here */
            break;
            default:
                    waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
                    /* check waitpid return code */
            break;
    }
```

Comment: @downvoter I would appreciate some feedback that would help me improve this answer :-)

Answer (score 4):

system() will work in conjunction with setuid() but that's the problem: major security risk. The problem is system() starts a shell (bash, sh, etc.) using whatever environment is in place, and when you intend for it to run "iptables", my PATH could point to my own version of iptables which I could easily convince you to run for me, as root. You can seem to solve that by using a full path to iptables, but other environment variables (LD_PRELOAD_PATH, for example) can be used to convince tools to load rogue shared libraries -- again, running things as root which were not intended.

For what you need to do, securely, you *must* use one of the exec() family, and you must take control over its operating environment. Anything else is asking for security abuse. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/environ.html appears to be a good place to learn more.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need to use `system()`?  The [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) is telling you exactly what to do:

> Use the [**`exec(3)`**](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exec) family of functions instead, but not [**`execlp(3)`**](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execlp) or [**`execvp(3)`**](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execvp).

You will probably be interested in the [`fork(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) and [`wait(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait) system calls as well.